# Revert inset/outset css style of div on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have to rework selection handled by checkboxes to selection with 'icons'.
To mark the 'icon' as selected, the background should change and also the shadow, so the icon looks like it's pressed inside (inset).

I thought that just by switching the shadow settings for each class I should get it done, but it's not working.

```
div.isntClicked {
  background-color: #0e8146;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1),
  inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
div.isClicked {
  background-color: #ffa500;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
  inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);    
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tqkk5g34/)

Green icon is not selected and outset.
Orange icon is selected and inset (not working)

Do I have a problem with css, jquery or is there some other problem I'm not aware off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/tqkk5g34/1/

Looks like you just had one of your box-shadow properties negative instead of positive:

CSS:

```
div.isClicked {
    background-color: #ffa500;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
                inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);    
}
```